# Why can't export variable members in a PowerShell module using VariablesToExport?

Tags: powershell, variables, module, powershell-module, module-export

From [How to Write a PowerShell Module Manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest) I learned that I can export all the variables in the module using `VariablesToExport = '*'`. However, after using it, I found that I could not export any variables.

After writing tests to confirm and reading more documentation, I didn't find the cause of the problem. I may have overlooked something important. What is going on here?

`TestModule.psm1` excerpt:

```powershell
0..9 | ForEach-Object { New-Variable -Name "v_$_" -Value $_ }
```

`TestModule.psd1` excerpt:

```powershell
@{ModuleVersion = '1.0';RootModule = 'TestModule.psm1';VariablesToExport = '*'}
```

`TestModule.Tests.ps1`:

```powershell
 # Confirm that the module has indeed been imported.
$ModuleName | Get-Module | ForEach-Object 'name' | Should -Be $ModuleName
 # All variables do not exist.
0..9 | ForEach-Object { "variable:v_$_" | Test-Path | Should -BeFalse }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is far from obvious, but, as of PowerShell 7.2, **in order to export *variables* from a PowerShell [module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules), listing them in the module [*manifest*](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-modulemanifest)'s (`*.psd1` file's) `VariablesToExport` entry *alone* is *not* enough**:

You ***also* need an [`Export-ModuleMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember) `-Variable` call in your *script module* file (`*.psm1`)** - be sure to **place it at the *end* of the file**, to ensure that all definitions to be exported have already been made.

**Caveat**:

- **Once a `*.psm1` module calls `Export-ModuleMember`, *all* definitions to be exported must be exported *explicitly*;** that is, `-Function`, `-Cmdlet`, and `-Alias` arguments must also be specified, as appropriate; in all cases, wildcard `*` can be used to specify *all* definitions of the given type, and more specific [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) name patterns may be used too.

E.g., to export all your `$v_*` variables, as well as all functions matching the name pattern `*-Foo*`, place the following at the bottom of your `*.psm1` file:

```bash
Export-ModuleMember -Variable v_* -Function *-Foo*
```

**Important**:

With a module that has a module manifest (`*.psd1`) - as is typical - and a script module (`*.psm1`), **the export logic is a *two*-step process**:

- ***Candidate* export definitions are all those definitions exported from the `*.psm1` *itself*** - either *implicitly*, or *explicitly* with `Export-ModuleMember` statements.

  - ***Implicit* exports** - i.e. automatic exports performed in the absence of `Export-ModuleMember` calls - comprise **all *functions* and *aliases*, but *not* variables**.
  - Curiously, for *dynamic* modules - in-memory modules created with [`New-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-module) - it is *functions only*.
- **The export-relevant manifest (`*.psd1`) entries** - `FunctionsToExport`, `AliasesToExport`, `VariablesToExport` (`CmdletsToExport` only applies to *binary* cmdlets exported from *assemblies*) - ***further filter down* these candidate exports** and the filtered results are a module's *effective* exports.

  - Note: As the comments in newly generated module manifests advise, wildcard patterns such as `'*'`, should be *avoided* in manifests, because they slow command discovery for [auto-loading modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading) down; definitions should be enumerated explicitly, by their full names.

---

**Debugging tips**:

- To see which definitions a given module exports, call [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) with the `-Verbose` switch.

  - The `Importing ...` lines are the exported definitions being imported into the caller's scope.
  - If the `*.psm1` file does *not* call `Export-ModuleMember`, you'll also see the two-step process described above in action: `Exporting ...` lines preceding the `Importing ...` ones describe the implicit *candidate* exports.
- To force an already imported module to be re-imported after modifying its definition, call `Import-Module` with the `-Force` switch.

Comment: The explanation on the document mentioned above is rather obscure, and it will be much better with this document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-modulemanifest?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: regarding "as of PowerShell 7.2"; did the default behavior change?  I have scripts that are no longer working & it seems like something changed here.

Comment: thanks.  I must be doing something wrong.  I posted a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73215604/powershell-module-export-variables).