# How to export variables from a PowerShell module

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.2

I've defined a variable in a `psm1` file but when I try to access it in another script, after importing the module, I'm not seeing the value set in the `psm1` file.

*globals.psm1*

```
$blah = "hello world"
```

*my-script.ps1*

```
Import-Module "$PSScriptRoot\globals.psm1" -Force -Verbose
Write-Output "blah: ${blah}"
```

*output*

> PS C:\blah> .\my-script.ps1
> VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\blah\globals.psm1'.
> blah: ''

I thought all variables get exported by default.  I must be interrupting this wrong:

> Specifies the variables that the module exports to the caller's session state. Wildcard characters are permitted. By default, all variables `('*')` are exported

source: [MSFT Docs -> How to write a PowerShell module manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest)
(`CTRL + F` on 'VariablesToExport' to find the quoted text)

---

And yes, if I export the variable, I can access it but the documentation says: 'By default, all varialbes `('*')` are exported so what am I doing wrong or misunderstanding?

*globals.psm1*

```
$blah = "hello world"
Export-ModuleMember -Variable blah
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your module is *not* using a [module *manifest*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Module_Manifests)** (a companion `.psd1` file whose `RootModule` entry points to your `.psm1` file in the case of script modules), whereas the documentation you quote pertains to module manifest-based modules.

**If a module consists *only* of a `.psm1` file**, and that file contains no [`Export-ModuleMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember) calls, the following rule applies:

- **Only *functions* and *aliases* are automatically exported**.
- Conversely, this means: in order to also export *variables*, you must use an `Export-ModuleMember` call - and if you do, the slate is wiped clean, so to speak, and you must explicitly specify *all* definitions you want to export (in the simplest case, use `Export-ModuleMember -Function * -Alias * -Variable *`).
  Also, be sure to place this call at the *end* of your `.psm1` file, to ensure that all definitions to export have already been defined.

*Caveat*, if a manifest (`.psd1`) *is* used:

- The manifest's `*ToExport` keys apply *on top* of what the `.psm1` file - implicitly or explicitly - exports, i.e. you can use it to *further narrow* what is to be exported, by *explicitly enumerating* the elements to export, which not only makes the module more self-describing, but also helps performance when PowerShell auto-discovers the commands in available, but not-(yet)-imported modules.
- Therefore, if a manifest-based module wants to export variables, it too must have an explicit `Export-ModuleMember` call in its `.psm1` file, with the manifest potentially narrowing down what variables are ultimately to be exported.

Generally, **exporting *variables* from modules is best *avoided***, because:

- it increases the risk of name collisions with variables of the same name defined elsewhere.
- *discovering* which variables are exported by what module isn't as well-known as use of [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) is in order to determine what module a given function, cmdlet, or alias comes from. This is because (a) modules that export variables are rare and users generally don't expect it, and (b) the [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) cmdlet - which *can* tell you what module a variable is defined in - isn't often used in practice.

---

To see which definitions a given module exports, pass `-Verbose` to the [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) call that imports it. Additionally, pass `-Force` in order to force *re-loading* of an already imported module.

Comment: "exporting variables from modules is best avoided", sure, I can see that  but what's the "right" way to share some variables amongst some scripts ? that's a rhetorical question as it's really a separate SO Q/A.

Comment: @spottedmahn: If you [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) (load with `. `) a `.ps1` file (regular script file), you'll (indiscriminately) see all its definitions, including variables.